# Incomplete CSS grid leaving first item blank instead of last

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to display an unknown number of items in a 3 column grid. CSS grid seems like the perfect solution and using it in its simplest form gives me 99% of what I'm looking for.

However! If I have 8 items, it will leave the first spot in row 1 empty and fill the rest of the grid. Example:

[image: grid with first item empty]

Instead, I want it to fill the first row and leave the final spot in the grid empty like this:

[image: grid with last item empty]

The CSS I'm using is:

```
.modules {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

The HTML is:

```
<div class="row modules">
  <div class="module">
  </div>
  ...
  <div class="module">
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to specify this behaviour or would it be simpler to switch to Flexbox?

Comment: what you want should be the default behavior.

Comment: @TemaniAfif There must be something else interacting with it that is reversing things somehow. I was surprised that it wasn't the default. I'll investigate further to see what could be causing this outcome. Thank you!

Comment: What is your CSS for row and module? Are there any parent elements with styles wrapped around your sample? I could not reproduce on my own with a minimal setup, given I had to make up for the missing classes. https://plnkr.co/edit/b6CL4CPj1E7B2wue?preview

Comment: @SteveHynding It turns out the CSS that had the unexpected/unwanted interaction was the setting of `content` in a before/after context. I posted an answer that gives more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found out what the issue was. There is an interaction between the grid layout and the `content` property that had an unexpected effect.

This CSS (used throughout the project I'm working on) resulted in the behaviour I was seeing:

```
.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: "";
}
```

Changing it to negate this property setting in this particular case reverted the behaviour to the default CSS grid behaviour that I was expecting:

```
.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: none;
}
```

Comment: better use `content: none`

Comment: @TemaniAfif I initially had `content: none` but thought it would be safer to change as little as possible. What is the benefit to using `none` rather than `inherit`?

Comment: `none` is the correct value because you don't want to have content. inherit means that it will inherit the value of its parent and since we almost never use `content` with any element it will fallback to none so it's safer to specify none instead of inherit to avoid rare special cases where it might not work